# Laravel app painfully slow in cpanel, is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have a laravel app deployed in cpanel with a MySQL database, the page is awfully slow to load (takes around a minute to load) is there a way to make it faster? It's perfectly fine in localhost so I guess it's a server thing but I don't know what to do to make it bearable

Changing server isn't an option I can do though.

Comment: Do you have option of SSH login root to your MySQL instance?  Able to get report from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;?  Can you edit your my.cnf file?

Answer (score 0):

When using Laravel or any frameworks in production, you have to cache the PHP compiled code. Or else, PHP has to compile the code for each requests. This can slowdown the application significantly.

Install the PHP OpCache extension and enable it in the configuration file.

Change following configuration settings as per your requirement

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128 # MB, adjust to your needs
opcache.max_accelerated_files=5000 # 5000 will be enough for a ed Laravel app.
opcache.revalidate_freq=5 #How often the cache has to be revalidated.
```

Restart the `php-fpm` and `apache` service or restart your server. This should speed up your application by 5x magnitudes.

Please note that if `opcache` is not configured to automatically revalidate, you will have to revalidate everytime you change the production code.

You can use this library to do the same https://github.com/appstract/laravel-opcache

Comment: where are the configuration settings for opcache? Do i have to configure this in my laravel app or in cpanel?

Comment: You have to SSH into your server and change the configuration on the opcache configuration file. Opcache is in no way related to Laravel, it's a PHP extension.